# Можно ли запретить кликать по ссылкам, которые равны текущей странице?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Так как сайт у некоторых может грузится долго, а любознательные пользователи любят кликать всюду, необходимо запретить кликать по ссылкам, которые равны текущей странице. Сложность в том, что страниц на сайте около 100 и нужно это сделать, изменив 1-2 файла.

Comment: А последней каплей будет перехват нажатия клавиш F5 и т.д.?

Comment: Можно, но осторожно)))

Comment: @DmitryDevelop Запретить можно либо скрыв поле, либо удалив href, либо сделать её не активной для нажатия. Либо вообще сделать появление через несколько секунд или минут после перехода по ссылке. К сожалению больше сказать невозможно, так как не видно, как у Вас там всё организовано.

Comment: @Denis640Kb если у ссылки убрать href, вам всё равно никто не запретит нажать на такую ссылку. Уж лучше добавить такой ссылке css класс, в котором написать     pointer-events: none;

Comment: @Quazimorda Тогда уж просто сделать не активной, чем добавлять классы.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, просто, не всегда хорошо. У элемента, которому прописали pointer-events: none; сбрасываются любые кастомные стили, если они были. Если было какое-нибудь позиционирование, то отменится и оно. Добавление стиля всё-таки не отменит всех прочих стилей, если они были.

Comment: @Quazimorda Категорически не согласен. Если есть необходимость скрыть поле, то это можно спокойно сделать через `js`. Но автор хочет именно сделать ссылку просто не кликабельной. Нет необходимости что-либо сбрасывать. Поэтому сделать ссылку не активной в этом случае не только проще, но и правильней.

Comment: @Denis640Kb так указанный стиль и убирает обработчик с нужного элемента. Точнее, убирает все обработчики и все стили, но это уже другое. ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если грубо то можно повесить обработчик на событие click любой ссылки и сверить текущую страницу с href ссылки, доработайте как вам необходимо:

```
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
    if (window.location.href == $(this).attr('href')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```